# Windows 7: Installing multiple R packages via script

Tags: r

I am trying to script the installation of R 2.15.1 on Windows 7.  R installs just fine, but I cannot figure out how to install multiple packages from the same batch script (or any batch script, for that matter).  Below is the part of the script where I call a simple R file.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\R\R-2.15.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "%~dp0R packages for GME.R"
```

Here is the contents of "R packages for GME.R" that has the packages to install.

```
install.packages("CircStats","coda","deldir","gplots","igraph","ks","odesolve","RandomFields",dep=TRUE)
```

Given [documented ownership and ACLs issues with writing to the default library folder in Windows](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-run-under-Windows-Vista_003f), I've tried the following:

1. Taking ownership of "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\library", then running `R CMD BATCH <file>` (no change);
2. Giving "Full Control" permissions to my user account on the same folder, then running `R CMD BATCH <file>` (no change);
3. Changing the library folder to another location via Rprofile.site, then running `R CMD BATCH <file>` (no change);
4. Running command via Rgui `install.packages("CircStats","coda","deldir","gplots","igraph","ks","odesolve","RandomFields",dep=TRUE)` (works).

So far, I have had no luck using CMD or batch scripts to install packages.  Is there something I'm missing?  Any alternative ways of scripting package installation would be greatly appreciated.

Also, the machines I will be installing on are for multiple users, so system-wide installations and configurations are preferred.

//

Edit 2012-11-06:
Here is the error message from the .Rout file:

```
install.packages("CircStats","coda","deldir","gplots","igraph","ks","odesolve","RandomFields",dep=TRUE)
Warning in install.packages("CircStats", "coda", "deldir", "gplots", "igraph",  :
  'lib = "coda"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("CircStats", "coda", "deldir", "gplots", "igraph",  : 
  unable to install packages
Execution halted
```

If I execute `library(coda)` afterwards, it gives `Error in library(coda) : there is no package called ‘coda’`.

Comment: How doesn't it "work" when you do it via command line? It gives you an error? It tells you it has succeeded but when you start R and `library(CircStats)` it says it's not installed? If you get some sort of error message, what error?

Comment: I think you forgot to wrap your list of package names in `c()`. Try `install.packages(c("CircStats","coda","deldir","gplots","igraph","ks","odesolve","RandomFields"), dep=TRUE)`

Comment: I added the error message from the .Rout to the original question above.  It appears that R cannot write to the library when calling `install.packages()` in this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The odesolve package is depreciated and has been replaced by deSolve. R 2.15.1 is throwing an error when encountering this package. It could be causing problems for you. Here's a script I use for installing packages for new R installs.

```
libs=c("CircStats","coda","deldir","gplots","igraph","ks","odesolve‌​","RandomFields")
type=getOption("pkgType")                           
    CheckInstallPackage <- function(packages, repos="http://cran.r-project.org",
       depend=c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo", "Suggests", "Enhances"), ...) {
         installed=as.data.frame(installed.packages())
    for(p in packages) {
        if(is.na(charmatch(p, installed[,1]))) { 
          install.packages(p, repos=repos, dependencies=depend, ...) 
                    }
      }
    } 
    CheckInstallPackage(packages=libs)
```

Comment: Perfect!  This works beautifully when called from a batch script as above (`R CMD BATCH <file>`).  There's a small syntax error on line 2: `type=getOption("pkgType"))` should be `type=getOption("pkgType")` (single parenthesis).